# d3.js loading a csv throwing a TypeError in Chrome and something [native code] in Safari

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

So I pushed a d3 project back in July and it was working. I pulled it down today to update and after running an `npm install` I'm getting errors from `d3.csv()`

With the following...

```
d3.csv('js/data/data1.csv', (returnedData) => {
    console.log('RETURNEDDATA', returnedData);
});
```

In Chrome's console it traces out an array of 10 objects that have the right column headers but the values are all `NaN` plus there's an extra attribute that reads...

```
1: TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Failed to parse URL from //localhost:80js/data/data1.csv
```

In Safari I get something similar but it reads...

```
0 {[native code]: "initializeFetchRequest@[native code]", 3P%: NaN, AST: NaN, BPM: NaN, FG%: NaN, …}
1 {[native code]: "[native code]"}
2 {[native code]: "fetch@[native code]"}
3 {[native code]: "_onFinish@http://localhost:3000/js/scripts-bundle.js:18:27206"}
4 {[native code]: "http://localhost:3000/js/scripts-bundle.js:18:26091"}
5 {[native code]: "emit@http://localhost:3000/js/scripts-bundle.js:12:30954"}
6 {[native code]: "finishMaybe@http://localhost:3000/js/scripts-bundle.js:18:13349"}
7 {[native code]: "endWritable@http://localhost:3000/js/scripts-bundle.js:18:13432"}
8 {[native code]: "end@http://localhost:3000/js/scripts-bundle.js:18:16918"}
9 {[native code]: "end@http://localhost:3000/js/scripts-bundle.js:18:29326"}
10 {[native code]: "send@http://localhost:3000/js/scripts-bundle.js:19:13018"}
11 {[native code]: "send@http://localhost:3000/js/scripts-bundle.js:8:4724"}
12 {[native code]: "http://localhost:3000/js/scripts-bundle.js:21:3849"}
13 {[native code]: "mightThrow@http://localhost:3000/js/scripts-bundle.js:15:6588"}
14 {[native code]: "http://localhost:3000/js/scripts-bundle.js:15:7221"}
```

Any idea what causes this? I've updated from 4.9.? to 4.10.2 with no success.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `package.json` file to `4.10.0`, run `npm install` or `npm update` again, and the problem seems to go away.

It looks like this is an issue with a dependency in the latest version of D3 -- namely something happening within the package `d3-request` version 1.0.6. If you roll back to D3 version 4.10.0 that uses the earlier version of `d3-request`, namely 1.0.5, which doesn't seem to have this problem.

I've raised an issue over at the `d3-request` repository so hopefully this is something that can be fixed in the next patch. Feel free to throw your own comment in there so that everyone can see this is an issue affecting more than one person: https://github.com/d3/d3-request/issues/29

And please add your own details there if they differ from what I've described.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently there's something happening when you install d3 with NPM. Wiping d3 out and importing the library from a CDN instead fixed my problem. Apparently, one of the NPM installed dependencies is messing things up with the URL. Note the `:80js` in `Failed to parse URL from //localhost:80js/data/data1.csv`